# How to transform and filter an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have an `array` with objects like this:

```
[
  {
    latitude: 00,
    longitude: 11
  },
  {
    latitude: 22,
    longitude: 33
  },
  {
    latitude: 00,
    longitude: 11
  }, 
]
```

I would like to convert and filter that array to another array, which contains arrays, which contain objects:

if longitude and latitude are equals, they should go to the same array, so, I need a new array like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      latitude: 00,
      longitude: 11
    },
    {
      latitude: 00,
      longitude: 11
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      latitude: 22,
      longitude: 33
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Where’s your attempt at this? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212)

Comment: What is your expected output for input, `[{longitude:11,latitude:00},{latitude:22,longitude:33},{latitude:00,longitude:11},]` ? Note that `JSON.stringify` will create a different string if the same object properties are ordered differently. This means your current accepted answer will group objects with the same latitude and longitude in different arrays if the latitude and longitude properties are ordered differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce` into an object whose keys represent the array objects' contents, and whose values are arrays, and create/push to the appropriate array:

```js
const input=[{latitude:00,longitude:11},{latitude:22,longitude:33},{latitude:00,longitude:11},]
const output = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, obj) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify(obj);
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
    a[key].push(obj);
    return a;
  }, {})
)
console.log(output);
```

Comment: OP may or may not consider this working for the input, `const input=[{longitude:11,latitude:00},{latitude:22,longitude:33},{latitude:00,longitude:11},]`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to add count field in `JSON` object add update `count` if you found same element twice otherwise above answer are looking good.

```js
var data = [{
        latitude: 00,
        longitude: 11
    },
    {
        latitude: 22,
        longitude: 33
    },
    {
        latitude: 00,
        longitude: 11
    },
]
var result = [];
data.forEach(val => {
    const filterIndex = result.findIndex(v => v.latitude == val.latitude && v.longitude == val.longitude);
    filterIndex == -1 ? result.push({ ...val,
        count: 1
    }) : result[filterIndex].count += 1;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `latitude` and `longitude` to create a unique key and push each object in an array for each unique key in an object accumulator. Then using `Object.values()` extract all values.

```js
const data = [ { latitude: 00, longitude: 11 }, { latitude: 22, longitude: 33 }, { latitude: 00, longitude: 11 }, ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{latitude, longitude}) => {
      const key = latitude + '_' + longitude;
      r[key] = r[key] || [];
      r[key].push({latitude, longitude});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your array into an object with latitude and longitude forms a unique key and push the values corresponding to it. And then get the array back using Object.values

Try following

```js
var arr = [ { latitude: 00, longitude: 11 }, { latitude: 22, longitude: 33 }, { latitude: 00, longitude: 11 }];

var map = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
var key = c.latitude + "_" + c.longitude;
  a[key] = a[key] || [];
  a[key].push(c);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(map));
```

For reference, [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 1):

This si the solution for the filtering first you reduce data in groups, then you  concat to a string.

```js
    var a = [{latitude:21,longitude:12},{latitude:211,longitude:2},];

    var mapped = a.reduce((acc, e) => {
        var key = '' +  e.latitude + ','+ e.longitude;
        if (!acc[key])  acc[key] = [e];
        else acc[key].push(e); 
       return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(Object.keys(mapped).map((key) => mapped[key]));

    // edit
    console.log(Object.values(mapped));
```

Comment: Does not work for the input, `const a=[{latitude:21,longitude:12},{latitude:211,longitude:2},]`

Comment: Both of your console log calls seem to group both objects into one array. What the OP seems to be asking is to group objects into the same array only if their longitude and latitude values are the same.

Comment: @גלעדברקן indeed, I missed that case, fixed the code! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a composed key for a hashtable to speed up the duplicate finding:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const {latitude, longitude} of array) {
   const key = latitude + "_" + longitude;
   if(hash[key]) {
     hash[key].push({longitude, latitude});
   } else {
     result.push(hash[key] = [{longitude, latitude}]);
   }
 }
```